# How to add format to an existing column (WebGrid.Column)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have an existing column declaration

```
grid.Column("ID", "", format: @<text><input id=... tons of html here .. >)
```

And I want to use it in my code. However, I don't really understand what this 
format" parameter is, and how to add it to an existing column? As In, I want to use `column.format = I don't know what`. I know that format is an argument of type `Func<dynamic, object>` , what means it's a function that takes a `dynamic` and returns `object`. But `WebGridColumn` doesn't have a function "format". Where can I find it?

Comment: Actually [it does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgridcolumn.format(v=vs.111).aspx).

Comment: @EmilioVicari You are right, I'm blind. Still I can't seem to work out how to use it, do you know how can I call it?

Comment: What do you mean by "call it"? It's a member of the `WebGridColumn` class that contains a function that's called (automatically) when a cell needs to be rendered (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgridcolumn.format(v=vs.111).aspx)). So technically you just need to set it, not call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To any person that might be wondering about this in the future: You can just type

`idColumn.Format = @<text> </text>`